# Fix Outlook 2010 folder order

Tags: outlook

We have a user that has hundreds of folders under "Inbox", including many more hundreds of folders nested within those folders.

They have noticed that in one of the nested folders, the folder order is no longer alphabetical, but is ordered seemingly randomly. Only for that folder though!

In Outlook 2010, you cannot manually order folders.

Is there a way to fix this? (It seems to only happen to people with many folders).

Comment: Oops, this was suppose to be posted on SuperUser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run outlook with:

> Outlook.exe /resetnavpane

This has fixed the issue.